# How to force Python JSON output to exclude 'L' from longs

Tags: python, json, long-integer

I have a script that creates JSON from the result of an SQL query. The problem I'm having is that the (epoch millisecond) timestamp of the records being output is a long, which is getting the standard Python `long` representation with the appended L, and not a 'proper' JSON number:

`{'status': 'default', 'ID': '7717''recordTimestamp': 1372651201000L, 'Latitude': 50.836689, 'Longitude': -53.879143}`

I am using `json.dumps(record)` to generate this, but I cannot figure out how to make the `long` a JSON-formatted number. Does anyone have a quick solution to this? 
Thanks!

Edit: using Python 2.7.4 on Ubuntu

Comment: You are looking at Python literals, which include an `L` for integers over `sys.maxint`. This is **normal** and has nothing to do with JSON. In other words, you have a 'proper' JSON number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appending ten digit integer to list concatenates some entries with an "L"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632751/appending-ten-digit-integer-to-list-concatenates-some-entries-with-an-l)

Comment: Agree with @MartijnPieters that the sample data you're looking at is really a Python `dict` and not a json str. Take a look at @falsetru's answer and the result gives you no `L`

Comment: I agree that this is a literal, but the result is not actually valid for interchange with another system that does not expect a python literal, and can handle a long formatted as such.

Comment: @user1886721: Python representation strings are not *meant* to be used in interchanges with other systems. The result of `json.dumps()` (which *is* meant to be used for data interchange) does **not** include it.

Comment: Since py3 has removed the distinction between int/long, would moving to 3 remove the literal representation?

Comment: This is not valid JSON *anyway*. JSON must have double quotes. As everyone says, use the actual `json.dumps` function to create JSON.

Comment: agh. downvote myself! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json.dumps` does not append trailing `L`.

```
>>> json.dumps({'status': 'default', 'ID': '7717', 'recordTimestamp': 1372651201000L, 'Latitude': 50.836689, 'Longitude': -53.879143})
'{"status": "default", "Latitude": 50.836689, "Longitude": -53.879143, "ID": "7717", "recordTimestamp": 1372651201000}'

>>> json.dumps(98765432109876543210L)
'98765432109876543210'
```

Comment: That is actually not valid JSON (python's JSON parser is not standard-compliant) -- the top-level object must be a map or an array, FWIW, but your point still stands.

Comment: @DanLecocq how so? The output is a JSON `str` and the top level of the content of this string is indeed an array/map, no?

Comment: I was meaning `json.dumps(98765432109876543210L)`, but yeah the first instance is fine :-) Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str()` function:

```
str(longInt)
```

to remove the trailing `L`

Answer (score 0):

See json doc:
Specializing JSON object encoding:

```
>>> import json
>>> def encode_complex(obj):
...     if isinstance(obj, complex):
...         return [obj.real, obj.imag]
...     raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
...
>>> json.dumps(2 + 1j, default=encode_complex)
'[2.0, 1.0]'
>>> json.JSONEncoder(default=encode_complex).encode(2 + 1j)
'[2.0, 1.0]'
>>> ''.join(json.JSONEncoder(default=encode_complex).iterencode(2 + 1j))
'[2.0, 1.0]'
```

So you can define your encode_complex method, do something with **int** or **long** type.